# Error on Creating Facade in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-facade

I try to create facade in laravel.

**My Facade :**

```
 namespace App\Facades;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

 class someclass_f extends Facade
 {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
      return new \App\Someclass();
    }
 }
```

**My Base Class :**

```
  namespace App;

  class Someclass
   {
     public function get($data = [])
      {
        echo "foo";
      }
   }
```

**In Calling :**

```
 use App\Facades\someclass_f; 

 class my_class{

    function(){
       someclass_f::get();
    }

 }
```

**I got error as :**

```
Class 'App\Facades\someclass_f' not found
```

What's wrong with this ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `Someclass::get()`? Your facade name is `someclass_f`.

Call it like: `someclass_f::get();` and that will call get() function in \App\Someclass.

Comment: sorry, i edited now. That's actually "someclass_f::get()".